# Error 404 Not Found EC2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy a flask application that I made with several pages and I'm following this tutorial to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ct1GbTvgVNM&t=94s&ab_channel=AMonkinCloud%E2%98%81%EF%B8%8F

Everything went fine but when I try connecting to my public IP address, I get the error 404 Not Found.

Could it be because something with my application?

If i user $ curl localgost:8000, it seems its working fine, getting this result:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<h1>Redirecting...</h1>
<p>You should be redirected automatically to the target URL: <a href="/login?next=%2F">/login?next=%2F</a>. If not, click the link.
```

Thanks in advanced!